# Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean using datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to put a date using datepicker and want to fetch and display rest of the values based on ID and datepicker value . I am consistently getting this error and notice.

> Notice: Undefined index: datepicker in C:\xampp\htdocs\easymed\access_form.php on line 58
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\easymed\functions.php on line 524

```
<tr><td>Date : </td><td>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p><input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
</td></tr>
```

**Script**

```
function fetchAppointments($DOCTOR_LICENSE_NO,$datepicker) {
  global $mysqli,$DOCTOR_LICENSE_NO, $datepicker;
 // $args = array($DOCTOR_LICENSE_NO, $datepicker);
  //echo $selected_speciality;
  //echo $args[0];
  //echo $args[1];
  //echo $args[2];
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare(
    "SELECT DOCTOR.DOCTOR_LICENSE_NO,
            DOCTOR.DOCTOR_FNAME, 
            DOCTOR.DOCTOR_LNAME, 
            DOCTOR.DOCTOR_EMAIL_ID,
            DOCTOR.DOCTOR_PHONE, 
            APPOINTMENT.APPOINTMENT_DATE,
            APPOINTMENT.APPOINTMENT_TIME,
            APPOINTMENT.APPOINTMENT_STATUS
            FROM (DOCTOR INNER JOIN APPOINTMENT ON DOCTOR.(DOCTOR_LICENSE_NO) = APPOINTMENT.(DOCTOR_LICENSE_NO)) WHERE $datepicker = APPOINTMENT.APPOINTMENT_DATE");                
  $stmt->bind_param("ss",$DOCTOR_LICENSE_NO, $datepicker);
  $stmt->execute();  
  $stmt->bind_result($DOCTOR_LICENSE_NO,$DOCTOR_FNAME, $DOCTOR_LNAME, $DOCTOR_EMAIL_ID, $DOCTOR_PHONE,$APPOINTMENT_DATE , $APPOINTMENT_TIME, $APPOINTMENT_STATUS);
  while ($stmt->fetch()){ 
    $row[] = array(
      'DOCTOR_LICENSE_NO'    => $DOCTOR_LICENSE_NO,
      'DOCTOR_FNAME'         => $DOCTOR_FNAME,
      'DOCTOR_LNAME'         => $DOCTOR_LNAME,
      'DOCTOR_EMAIL_ID'      => $DOCTOR_EMAIL_ID,
      'DOCTOR_PHONE'         => $DOCTOR_PHONE,
      'APPOINTMENT_DATE'     => $APPOINTMENT_DATE , 
      'APPOINTMENT_TIME'     => $APPOINTMENT_TIME, 
      'APPOINTMENT_STATUS'  =>  $APPOINTMENT_STATUS
      
      );
   }
  $stmt->close();
  return ($row);
 }`
```

Comment: I can't get you actually how you are calling your `fetchAppointments` method. But I can guess one thing is that you need to provide `name` to your `input` field so that it can be accessed in `php` `$_POST` `globals`.

Comment: `prepare()` is failing and returning `false` (there's your boolean). Execute this at the top of your script for better error reporting in MySQLi ~ `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`